# Center text vertically in grid with tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I was trying to create a responsive grid layout with *tailwindcss* but I could not center the texts vertically in grid. All I could do was center the text horizontally with `text-center`.

```
<body>
  <div class="grid gap-5 grid-flow-row grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-6 text-center ">
    <div class="border-2 rounded-lg h-20 lg:h-32">Text</div>
    <div class="border-2 rounded-lg h-20 lg:h-32">Text</div>
    <div class="border-2 rounded-lg h-20 lg:h-32">Text</div>
    <div class="border-2 rounded-lg h-20 lg:h-32">Text</div>
    <div class="border-2 rounded-lg h-20 lg:h-32">Text</div>
    <div class="border-2 rounded-lg h-20 lg:h-32">Text</div>
    ...
    <div class="border-2 rounded-lg h-20 lg:h-32">Text</div>
</body>
```

Demo in [codepen](https://codepen.io/farhan2077/pen/JjXOgjM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with flex. Just add this `flex justify-center items-center` to every text div, like that:

```
<div class="border-2 rounded-lg h-20 lg:h-32 flex justify-center items-center">Text</div>
```

It will make it flex container with children centered both horizontally and vertically.

And you can also remove `text-center` from wrapper since it will be redundant.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Now I see this and it got me thinking why I didn't think of that. Guess I still have to learn a lot more since I recently started learning web development.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `justify-self-center` to horizontally center text inside grid column. and `self-center` to vertically center text/content inside grid column. For added clarity, `content-center` to vertically center grid Column, aka like a child div inside parent grid container. `justify-center` for horizontal. The question you have to ask is, do I want to effect the grid column position? or the grid column contents position?